# Sword attack direction bugged?

Tags: xcom-2

When having your ranger selected and you move your cursor on the enemy tile you can choose which direction to attack from. Once the direction is locked in you would still have to select a weapon (i.e. sword) and confirm to attack. This used to work fine for me until now.

However, now selecting the weapon after locking in the direction will deselect the target and pick a random new target. Changing the target at this point means not getting to select a direction of attack again, but getting a preselected random one.

Selecting the weapon first doesn't allow one to pick the direction of attack.

Does anyone know why this happens and how to fix it?

(note: it now spans multiple missions / reboots, so it doesn't seem to be going away by itself... my rangers just became basically unusable in melee)

Comment: Can't you just move to the square you want to attack from first, then attack?

Comment: I've never had the chance to select a direction AND THEN select the weapon. What exactly are you doing?

Comment: don't know if it is bugged, but you should be able to hold ctrl mouse over the spot you want and push it into the enemy you wish to hit and it'll change to a sword attack icon then just right click and it should do the attack

Comment: I know of two ways to do a sword attack. Are you doing something else? 1) Use the Slash menu option and pick a target. This doesn't allow you to pick the square you attack from, but shows you the chance to hit. 2) Right click on the enemy. You choose which square you attack from by where you click on the border of the enemy's square. There's an icon showing you which square you will attack from.

Comment: You're not supposed to press the attack ability after hovering the mouse, you're supposed to right click on the target.

Comment: The best way to use Slash imo is to click and hold RMB next to the Enemy and then drag onto the enemy to attack.

Comment: Odes the RMB work for skull mining too?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft, that would make it impossible to attack after dashing (something a sword attack can normally do).

Comment: @peper757, hmm, strange. When I select direction and right click, the attack doesn't start right away, I still have to confirm it (same as with shooting). I guess that is normal?
What I'm guessing is the problem is that for me, after right-clicking the enemy, it's always the shotgun that is selected - and changing back to sword selects another target, or if that's the only one - another direction.

Comment: Note though that for me this worked like that from the start, I would right click the sword icon on the enemy, the shotgun would be selected as default weapon, I would simply change it to sword, and confirm the attack.
It just suddenly stopped behaving like that and started resetting the target when switching to sword.

Are you guys saying that the sword attack starts immediately on right-click for you, without any confirmation needed?

Comment: YOU CAN SWORD-ATTACK AFTER DASHING!?!?!

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Yeah, and get this; you can miss and die horribly after dashing too! ;)

Comment: @quetzy That sounds odd, as others have mentioned, the attack should just start straight away. Have you tried validating your files?

Comment: @peper757, well, starting with my last playing session - the attack is now starting right away on rightclick. Unfortunately, I am unsure what the causes were :(

Still, thanks for the help guys!

Comment: @quetzy No problem, dude, that's what we're here for.